# Open Swagger UI page with authentication set

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am working on application like developer portal, where developer login and have an option to open various swagger pages from React application and swagger pages have security turn ON.
To improve developer experience, is there any way to pass user session to swagger page so user won't need to click "Authorize"  button   and can try any endpoint

About my stack, spring boot 2.7 version, open api 3.0 and react